# Python venv: activation method compatible with both Windows and POSIX (macOS, Ubuntu)

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, python-venv, virtual-environment

To activate a Python virtual environment (`venv`) on:

- macOS: involves `venv/bin/activate`

  - `venv` dir contains: `bin include lib pyvenv.cfg`
- Windows: involves `venv/Scripts/activate`

  - `venv` dir contains: `Include/ Lib/ Scripts/ pyvenv.cfg`
  - Note: users are okay with using MinGW via Git Bash

I have both Windows and POSIX (mainly macOS and Ubuntu) users. I would like to have a `bash` script (hence Git Bash) they both can run that involves `venv` activation.

Is there a standard/simple way I can activate the venv on either OS?  Currently, the fact that Windows uses `Scripts` and POSIX uses `bin` is the problem I am hitting.

---

Update: I was hoping there's a better way than manually adding `if`/`else` logic to the `bash` script to connect these dots.  However, if someone knows a particularly elegant way of doing this `if`/`else` in one line, it's probably the best quick fix.

Comment: Just test to see which directory and script is present based on the OS.

Comment: I'd use pipenv package for x-platform management. Command should be same: pipenv shell
https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/#usage-examples